# added attribute in data model sections not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, core-data

I am building a core data based app. I added the attribute "category_en" to my "Recipe" data model :

```
Recipe.h

@interface Recipe : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category_en;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cookingTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc_en;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc_it;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * included;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ingredients_en;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ingredients_it;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name_en;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name_it;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * photo;

@end
```

And I create the sections in the table view with this code:

```
if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"it"])
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 =
        [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"category" ascending: YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 =
        [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"name_it" ascending: YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil]];
} else
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 =
        [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"category_en" ascending: YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = 
        [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"name_en" ascending: YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil]];
    }
```

and

```
if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"it"]) {
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
      [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest 
          managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
          sectionNameKeyPath:@"category"
          cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
} else {
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
      [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest
                managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                sectionNameKeyPath:@"category_en"
                cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
}
```

When I execute the app the sections are visible only using italian language and not in english, which instead throws this error:

```
CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) A section returned nil value
for section name key path 'category_en'.
Objects will be placed in unnamed section
```

The SQL database is filled with the necessary data and the category_en attribute is also set as optional.

UPDATE:

I tried with this code... still not working..

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: NSLocalizedString(@"CATEGORY_KEY", nil) ascending: YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: NSLocalizedString(@"NAME_KEY", nil) ascending: YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil]];

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:NSLocalizedString(@"CATEGORY_KEY", nil)cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

Comment: Have you **@syntesize** your new column?

Comment: I recreated the "Recipe" NSManagedObject subclass so I think it's ok.

Comment: I suppose you need to delete the cache before switching controller, because the sort descriptor has changed. This may also be the cause of your section problem.

Comment: I updated the first post with more info.

Comment: I solved recreating the sql database